# Issue regarding running WCF server and client

Tags: c#, wcf

i am very new in WCF and still learning the sugar of WCF. i never develop any WCF apps for production environment. for a long time i was searching a good article with source code for Screen sharing apps and at last i found it with sample code.

Mr bob cravens develop a small application for screen sharing between two pc which is fully WCF saved apps. i go through their code and understand few things and still few things i mean few flow is not clear to me. i need to run this apps at my end just to clear the whole thing like how server & client communicate and send screen shot in each other.

when i tried to run this wcf server from the sample code then i found it is running but the problem lies at wcf client end. when i try to run wcf client end then i am getting error.

the error is : - **HTTP could not register URL [http://mypcip:myport/Rlc/Viewer/][1]. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see).**

this error occur when this line execute at wcf client side and lines are

```
 Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://mypcip:myport/Rlc/Viewer");
 _viewerService = new ServiceHost(typeof(ViewerService), baseAddress);
 _viewerService.Open();
```

when service host try to open and this line execute then error occur.

```
_viewerService.Open();
```

i try to change the port also from 1003 to 8080 but got same error.
i post the problem in that site from where i got this code but got no answer and also found lot other people also post the same kind of problem and got no answer.

from where any one can download the source code and try to run this apps at their end and can tell me what is wrong in this code which causes error when i try to run this sample code wcf client in my pc. i tried lot to understand why client is giving error but could not understand.

so it my request that please anyone download the source code and just run the server first and then run the client editing ip address in code and definitely encounter error. tell me what i need to change in this code as a result i can run this apps perfectly in my pc. to go through the source code with debug mode is very important job for me but i am not being able to run this apps at all. so please help me becoz i am in problem. thanks

Comment: Are you sure you SUBSTITUTE ip and port with concrete values in "mypcip:myport" (like "192.168.11.12:12345 where 192.168.11.12 is "your-pc-ip")?

Comment: yes i did...it would better if u download this sample code from bobcravens.com/files/RemoteDesktop.zip and run at ur end then u can see wcf client end giving error. if u go through this code then u like it because of its purpose. so please download and help me. thanks

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the specific code. It is rather that your process doesn't have enough permissions to create a WCF endpoint. I suggest you turn off the UAC and/or run the application "as the administrator" (right click on the executable in the os shell)

Comment: how to run the wcf client from VS2010 IDE with admin privilege rather right clicking on exe and selecting run as administrator

Comment: Run VS "as administrator".

Comment: ok i will try to run wcf client as admin mode and get back to u. thanks

Comment: It is not the client, but rather the server to be run "as admin".

Comment: thanks ur tips works. :)

Comment: Thomas, @WiktorZychla's suggestion does the same as mine. My approach is a little more generic because it allows all processes to use those address/port and not just that VS instance you start with admin rights. When you close VS, the priviledges are gone and next time you need to start as admin again. In my approach VS may start with restricted priviledges and would still be able to run the mentioned client/server solution.

Comment: @JensH: I haven't actually tried this but +1 from me for this generic approach.

Comment: when i run server & client end in same pc with admin privileged then everything works fine but when i run server with admin privileged in another machine then server is running fine but client which is running in another pc not being able to connect to server end. security mode set none and firewall off at server end but still client could not connect to server...can u plzz tell me why....what could be the problem. how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem.

What the error message tells you is that you need to **explicitly allow it** to run on the configured address and port.

This will need *administrative priviledges.*

What to do to solve this, depends on which OS you are actually trying to run the service on.

When running on **Windows XP** or **Server 2003**, you will need to configure it in the command line with this pattern

```
httpcfg set urlacl /u {http://URL:Port/ | https://URL:Port/} /aACL
```

If you are running **Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 R2** or **Windows 7** you need to use the `netsh.exe` tool:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```

And finally you might need to configure an exception in the **firewall rules** to allow for this service to run on your configured address/ port: [Open a port in Windows Firewall](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall)

I solved this issue with the help of these Microsoft articles resources:

- [Httpcfg Syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781601%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms733768.aspx)

Comment: previous i works with wcf for learning purpose and i could run wcf server and client end in my pc. my OS is win7. i never configure anything such with netsh. then why should i configure now for this apps. it will be very helpful if u just download the apps...i gave url from where u can download. please run the server & client in ur pc....then u can see where it stuck. i guess something need to be change in code. please download once to determine the problem. thanks

Comment: u told me to use this netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user but in my home pc there is no domain....just work group there. so what will be the statement for workgroup on win7 ?

Comment: when i am running wcf client on win 7 then i think i should not to create any port for that. port is require to run for server end. am i right ??